# Ember JS: Reloading entire collection after record insertion

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm Using ember 1.13.8 and rails 4 in back-end. I'm having an 'item' model in my app. How can i force ember to reload items route which contains all the items collection after inserting an item record.Here are my route files for items and create:

```
app/routes/items/create.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(){
       return this.store.createRecord('item');
    },
    actions: {
      create: function(){
         var self=this;
         self.controller.get('model').save().then(
            function() {
                self.transitionTo('items');
         });
      }     
    }
});
```

---

```
app/routes/items.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(){
        return this.store.findAll('item');
    }
});
```

After inserting a record, i'm using transitionTo to go to the items route which does not automatically reloads the model, so how can i make ember to reload data from server.

Comment: Your new "item" record is not added to the "items" list ?

Comment: The item gets added to the "items" list, but doesn't show up in the "items" list until i refresh the "items" route manually.

Comment: store.findAll('item', { reload: true });  //enforces getting fresh data

Comment: But the model hook doesn't get called on transitionTo the route. It works when i used it as an action, but i want to use it as a hook that gets automatically called on transitionTo.

Comment: You newly created item should be already in the store if u wish you can unload items or call the refers..

Answer (score 0):

Try one of the following :

1. call reset() on the controller instance or
2. call refresh() on the router instance.
3. call model.reload()

That should reload the model for you :)

Comment: Calling refresh worked for me using it as an action but i want to use it as a hook that gets executed upon transitionTo  the route.

Comment: And it won't work with in a hook? Just fire an action from the handler function then..wouldn't that do the job?

Comment: nope, it won't work within a hook, because the hook doesn't get executed on transitionTo the "Items" route.